# unable to retrieve the applications and unable to create the subscription for the API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 API manager 3.1.0
I am using REST APIs for creating the subscriptions for the application. I am using the REST API
https://x.x.x.x:9443/apis/api/am/store/v1.0/subscriptions
I am using basic auth for the authentication of the API. My request body is as follows.

```
{
    "applicationId": "6451faaa-65aa-48dc-8655-2ffb623fc441",
    "apiId": "ed94f936-7e8a-4c62-92e6-92991aca4348",
    "throttlingPolicy": "Unlimited"
}
```

When I send this request I am getting the 200 OK response but the content of the 200 OK is the management console login page. This is one issue I am facing. Another issue is a very basic one- I am trying to get the applications created in the system for that I am using below API

```
https://x.x.x.x:9443/api/am/store/v1.0/applications?limit=25&offset=0
```

again with basic authorization. for this request I am getting the 404 response. Same response I get if I change the authentication to Oauth token.

I tried these APIs with multiple tenant users credentials but for all I am getting the same response.

**UPDATE:**

I have obtained the access token like below:

```
1.  curl --insecure -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @payload.json https://localhost:9443/client-registration/v0.16/register
```

I got the response

```
{"clientId":"MPPomfxrQ_ZReRlHz0x70pU6yLca","clientName":"rest_api_store","callBackURL":"www.google.lk","clientSecret":"dQrYXtwMG8fB4Qhu7NfC1uqLAkwa","isSaasApplication":true,"appOwner":"admin","jsonString":"{\"grant_types\":\"password refresh_token\",\"redirect_uris\":\"www.google.lk\",\"client_name\":\"rest_api_store\"}","jsonAppAttribute":"{}","tokenType":null}

2.  curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=apim:subscribe" -H "Authorization: Basic TVBQb21meHJRX1pSZVJsSHoweDcwcFU2eUxjYTpkUXJZWHR3TUc4ZkI0UWh1N05mQzF1cUxBa3dh" https://10.57.8.36:9443/oauth2/token
```

and I got the response

```
{"access_token":"194d3a3c-8f37-3459-a909-f1f871f096dc","refresh_token":"be7bfcb5-970d-3a8b-8f0a-d69fb7ea53fb","scope":"apim:subscribe","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}
```

using the obtained token if I place the API request I get still 404

Comment: You need to get an OAuth2 token to access the API. - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/product-apis/devportal-apis/devportal-v1/guide/

Comment: I tried with JWT token as well it did not work. Do you mean it does not work with JWT and works only with opaque oauth2 tokens

Comment: I tried with oauth token as well but the same issue

Comment: I havr updated the steps with oauth token please let me know your thoughts

Comment: Can u try the following?

curl -X GET "https://apis.wso2.com/api/am/store/v1/subscriptions?apiId=ed94f936-7e8a-4c62-92e6-92991aca4348&applicationId=6451faaa-65aa-48dc-8655-2ffb623fc441&offset=0&limit=25" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer TOKEN"

Comment: I was trying with v1.0 as mentioned in the docs. But it is actually v1. This is  documentation bug.

Comment: Can u point to the v1.0 stated in the doc? I could nt find any reference. This will help to fix if there is any

Comment: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/develop/product-apis/devportal-v1/#/Applications/post_applications. Execute any of the APIs. the execution link will have the v1.0 instead of v1 . Also base url is Base URL: apis.wso2.com/api/am/store/v1.0

Comment: Can you please check whether you know anything about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62819620/unable-to-generate-the-application-keys-using-rest-api-in-wso2-api-manager