# Unable to generate the application keys using REST API in WSO2 API manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using API manager 3.1.0 I want to generate the application keys for the application I created using the REST API. My API request is as follows:

```
https://x.x.x.x:9443/api/am/store/v1/applications/bc87abf6-8e84-40d5-84ff-2a6fbb446eed/generate-keys
```

**Request Body is as follows**

{
"keyType": "PRODUCTION",
"grantTypesToBeSupported": [
"Code"
]
}

For this rquest I am getting the below response

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal server error",
    "description": "The server encountered an internal error. Please contact administrator.",
    "moreInfo": "",
    "error": []
}
```

In the logs I see the below error logs.

```
TID: [-1234] [api/am/store] [2020-07-09 15:59:09,911] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl} - Could not execute Workflow org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete_aroundBody2(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:66)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute_aroundBody0(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:54)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration_aroundBody144(APIConsumerImpl.java:3876)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:3745)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:505)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.store.v1.ApplicationsApi.applicationsApplicationIdGenerateKeysPost(ApplicationsApi.java:125)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.handleException_aroundBody78(APIUtil.java:1932)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.handleException(APIUtil.java:1930)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:170)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:123)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication_aroundBody6(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:119)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:116)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete_aroundBody2(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:78)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : carbonApplication4_PRODUCTION
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager.handleException_aroundBody6(AbstractKeyManager.java:165)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager.handleException(AbstractKeyManager.java:163)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication_aroundBody0(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication_aroundBody8(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:145)
        ... 63 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.fromOM(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:3386)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:1377)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:64)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo_aroundBody42(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:720)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:715)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication_aroundBody0(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:125)
        ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.xsd.ErrorHandler$Factory.parse(ErrorHandler.java:616)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.xsd.APIManagementException$Factory.parse(APIManagementException.java:416)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.types.axis2.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException$Factory.parse(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException.java:417)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.fromOM(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:3156)
        ... 70 more
```

This has causedby exception line as

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : carbonApplication4_PRODUCTION
```

What is the error here. I have changed the host name of my server to IP address but did not regenerate the certificate with CN containing the IP address. Is this error because of wrong CN name in the certificate? But I can create the keys from the dev portal successfully. Please let me know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the Generate Key failed in the first attempt to some reason leaving an incomplete Service Provide Application. Can you check if you have a Service Provider app named _carbonApplication4_PRODUCTION. If so can you delete it and re-try?